# How to put dir .apt_generated to gitignore

Tags: android, git, gitignore

I put to the .gitignore file

```
.apt_generated
```

but everytime after recompiling the project eGit in Eclipse and `git status -s` show that the files in .apt_generated are changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you added it to the `.gitignore` after you committed it once, you need to remove it from the index by typing

```
git rm --cached .apt_generated
```